# javascript: Преобразовать объект в массив

Tags: javascript

Как преобразовать такой объект в обычный массив?

```
function site(sel,sel2,sel3,sel4,sel5){
this.sel = sel;this.sel2 = sel2;this.sel3 = sel3;this.sel4 = sel4;this.sel5 = sel5;
}

var a = new site('<div>','<b>','hello','</b>','</div>');
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Преобразование объект в массив JavaScript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/855833/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перебрать все элементы объекта и запихнуть их в массив.

```js
function site(sel,sel2,sel3,sel4,sel5){
    this.sel = sel;this.sel2 = sel2;this.sel3 = sel3;this.sel4 = sel4;this.sel5 = sel5;
}

var a = new site('<div>','<b>','hello','</b>','</div>');

var arr = [];
for(var index in a) { 
    arr.push(a[index]) 
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто запоминать в объекте переданные параметры – они сразу доступны в виде [массиво-подобного объекта `arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

```js
function site(sel,sel2,sel3,sel4,sel5) {
  this.arr = (arguments.length === 1 ? [arguments[0]] : Array.apply(null, arguments));
  this.sel = sel;this.sel2 = sel2;this.sel3 = sel3;this.sel4 = sel4;this.sel5 = sel5;
}

var a = new site('<div>','<b>','hello','</b>','</div>');
// массив в a.arr:   ["<div>", "<b>", "hello", "</b>", "</div>"]

document.body.innerHTML = 
JSON.stringify(a.arr).replace(/&/g,'&amp;').replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;');
```

Comment: `arguments` - это не `Array`

Comment: уже обновил ответ )

Comment: А проверка длины зачем? А, всё, понял. Чтобы единственное число не портило результат.

Comment: Upd. разобрался. `Array(4)` создаст массив из 4 элементов, а `Array(4,5)` – массив с двумя элементами: `[4,5]`

Comment: Да, я знаю. Просто не сразу дошло, что ты конструктор вызываешь вместо классического варианта.

Answer (score 1):

Странно, что никто не предложил:

```
Object.values(a);
```

Comment: `Object.values` довольно плохо поддерживался браузерами два года назад

Comment: @Grundy, почему вы постоянно упоминаете старые версии? Вы живете прошлым веком?

Comment: @And, потому что в ответ к старому вопросу спросили почему не предложили вариант, который еще не работал во время задания вопроса.

Comment: @Grundy, Кажись не 2016, а в 2015, если на то пошло.

Comment: @And, не понял комментарий