# Преобразование объект в массив JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Имеется такой объект:

```
var json_data = {"city":"Shanghai","country": "China", "car": "China"}
```

Как в JavaScript преобразовать его в вид массива и каждый key с его value был отдельный объект:

```
[
  {"city":"Shanghai"},
  {"country": "China"},
  {"car": "China"}
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте цикл for..in, в теле которого при каждой итерации в массив будет записан новый объект, состоящий из ключа / значения нужного объекта.

```
var json_data = {"city":"Shanghai","country": "China", "car": "China"}
var arr = [];
for (let key in json_data) {
    arr.push({[key]: json_data[key]})
}
```